# Advice for simpleTraverse usage from "@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree"

Tags: typescript-eslint

I'm parsing AST with `typescript-estree`'s `parse` function and traversing the tree with `simpleTraverse` to identify and collect metadata about different nodes. I read in [this issue discussion](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/3647#issuecomment-884372151) that `simpleTraverse` is intentionally not documented as it's only intended for usage by other ESlint packages, which makes sense.

My question is whether it's fine to use as is, or whether there's another tool I should be using. I have tried other common traversal tools, but the types are incomplete and / or conflict with what's provided by `@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree`. Another option is to copy the `simpleTraverse` [code](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/typescript-estree/src/simple-traverse.ts).

Thanks in advance! I really appreciate this project and the community supporting it. ❤️